# Is it possible to use the result from a `whereHas`-query in another `whereHas`?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I want to filter results of one subquery with the result of another  (which are sharing the same relations). Something like this:

```
modelA::whereHas('modelB', function ($query) {
    $query->select('modelC_id');
})
->whereHas('modelD', function ($query) {
    $query->where('field', 'modelC_id')
});
```

For this example, assume the following relations:

- modelA->hasMany('modelB')
- modelA->hasMany('modelD')
- modelB->hasOne('modelC')
- modelD->hasOne('modelC')

Models and relations are all working as they should, but I want modelA to lookup the modelC value through modelB, and then use this to filter the lookup on modelC through modelD.

I can do all this by looking up the value and use this on a second query, but it would be nice if I can use this in one statement (since the value can be looked up in the query!) so I can create a local scope on modelA.

Another option would be to add the related field to the resultset which I can then use in the `where`-query, but I cannot figure out how to get `modelC_id` in the resultset...

Is this possible?

Comment: Show the DB schema and relations in your question.

Comment: I tried to explain a little more, hope this helps

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this question ? I am looking for same solution

Comment: I ended up using a local scope with a custom query (using the querybuilder), so more a workaround instead of an answer to this question...